# NSMinuteCalenderUnit Versus kCFCalenderUnitMinute

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How can we differentiate between NSMinuteCalenderUnit and kCFCalenderUnitMinute ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're exactly equal and equivalent, but are defined separately because `CFCalendar` and `NSCalendar` are separate interfaces into the same subsystem (insert comment about toll-free bridging here.)

For consistency with Apple's APIs and to ensure readable code, you should use the `kCF` constants with Core Foundation functions and the `NS` constants with Cocoa methods/classes.

Comment: Appreciate your answer but can you please guide me  in what cases we should  use kCF constant and in what  cases we should use NS Constant ??

Comment: I already answered that question. 9 times out of 10, you should use `kCF` constants with Core Foundation and `NS` constants with Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. From the definition of `NSCalendarUnit`:

`NSMinuteCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitMinute`

Use `NSMinuteCalendarUnit` whenever an argument or variable is typed `NSCalendarUnit` (usually within Objective-C frameworks like Foundation and Cocoa). Use `kCFCalendarUnitMinute` whenever the variable or argument is typed `CFCalendarUnit` (usually within Core Foundation code).

Comment: Yes that is true according to calender units  enum{NSMinuteCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitMinute} but can u please tell me  which one should be used at what time ??? or we can use either of them ???

Comment: Okay thanx .satisfied with your answer.